# Ajax Auto-complete Text Box in ASP.NET does not work within master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, autocomplete

This example works fine with a normal asp.net page. but using with a master page , it does not work.

**The masterpage.master**

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxSearchCompany" class="form-control" placeholder="Search company..." runat="server"/>
                         <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="txtName_AutoCompleteExtender" runat="server" DelimiterCharacters="" Enabled="True" ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList" 
                            ServicePath="" TargetControlID="TextBoxSearchCompany" UseContextKey="True" MinimumPrefixLength="2" CompletionInterval="10" EnableCaching="true" CompletionSetCount="3">
                        </asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

**The masterpage code behind**

```
        [System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute(), System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethodAttribute()]
    public static string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count, string contextKey)
    {
        string connectionString = ConnectionString.GetConStr();
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        // Try to use parameterized inline query/sp to protect sql injection
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP " + count + " company FROM [vwCompanyLookup] WHERE company LIKE '" + prefixText + "%'", conn);
        SqlDataReader oReader;
        conn.Open();
        List<string> CompletionSet = new List<string>();
        oReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
        while (oReader.Read())
            CompletionSet.Add(oReader["company"].ToString());
        return CompletionSet.ToArray();
    }
```

any help to solve to this problem.

Comment: I have also the same issue. 
For me the Auto-Complete doesn't work on every page where I have included the master page (my auto complete code is inside the pages that included the master page) . 
I end up adding my Master page directly to the page where I use Autocomplete :( . very very dirty solution as changes on my master page will not going to be reflected on those pages. any help would be appriciated

Answer (score 0):

type service name in servicepath  --> GetCompletionList